# How do I get access to event.target in jquery event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have the following angularJS markeup:

```
<article ng-controller="GalleryListCtrl">
<details ng-repeat="gallery in galleries" gallery-repeat-directive>
    <summary>{{gallery.name}}</summary>
    <div class="image-gallery">
        <div ng-repeat="child in gallery.children">
            <img src="/Album/Image/{{gallery.name}}/Thumbnail/{{child}}" onclick="previewImage(this);" />
        </div>
    </div>
</details>
```

When this markup loads I have an event that hides the divs:

```
var stephensApp = angular.module('stephensApp', ['ngResource', 'ngSanitize'])
.directive('galleryRepeatDirective', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            if (scope.$last === true) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    scope.$emit('ngRepeatFinished');
                });
            }
        }
    }
});
```

In the event handler I have the following code:

```
    $scope.$on('ngRepeatFinished', function (ngRepeatFinishedEvent) {
    if (! isChrome()) {
        $('details div:first-of-type').hide();
        $('details').bind('click', function (event) {
            console.log(event);
            $(event.target).find('div').first().show();
        });
    }
});
```

In my Firefox browser, I am getting the div to hide correctly, but when I click the details, the log entry writes to the debugger, so I know the event is firing.  But I cannot make the div show again.   How do I find the div for the clicked on details tag?

Comment: Have you tried `$('details div').bind('click'` and `$(this).show();`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it did not work.  The problem is the div is hidden so I cannot click on it.  I need to get to the div from the details tag.

Comment: How about `$(this).children('div').first().show();`